# Not able to execute AZ comments using System.Management.Automation lib in IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, iis, asp.net-web-api

i wanted to execute the az login using System.Management.Automation. its working in my local. when i tried to deploy the same in web server, the system is not recognizing AZ comments

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IList<PSObject> Get()
        {
           

            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript("Import-Module Azure; az login");

                var token = ps.Invoke();

                return token;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Just because you haven't confirmed, you have done the install and import cmdlets for AZ, right? can you do a get-module * and share results?

Comment: Yes Matthew, I've already installed AZ cmdlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your managed account has the permission to execute the powershell from IIS, you can try to set the IIS application pool identity. For example, you can set Identity to LocalSystem.

Comment: this helps,  but still **AZ login popup**  is not getting triggered

Comment: How did you try it? Use F12 to see if there are error messages in the Console.